# why I'm getting NotSerializableException exception though I've implemented 'Serializable'

Tags: java, file, exception, serialization

I've implemented Serializable in class 'userInfo'. Still I'm getting exception. Here's the output console -

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: chatservernazmus.User
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1333)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at chatservernazmus.Server.getAllUser(Server.java:74)
        at chatservernazmus.Server.<init>(Server.java:44)
        at chatservernazmus.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Here are my two classes:

```
public class userInfo implements Serializable{
    public ArrayList<User> allUser=new ArrayList<User>();

    public void addUser(User e){
        allUser.add(e);
    }
    public ArrayList<User> getAllUser(){
     return allUser;
    }
}


public class User{
    public String userName="";
    public String password="";
    public String statusMessage="";
    public ArrayList<String> friend=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>offlineMessage=new ArrayList<String>();

    public User(String username,String password,String message){
        userName=username;
        password=password;
        statusMessage=message;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String message){
        statusMessage=message;
    }
    public void addFriend(String fr){
        friend.add(fr);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getOfflineMessage(){
        ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();
        offlineMessage.clear();
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should provide some codes in which you get error

Comment: Have you implemented on the class User? Which the error states! I don't know if 'userInfo' is User

Comment: Check all the objects at the last two lines mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: Check Server.java line 44 but really bro no code?!?! lets see some code

Comment: Here are my two classes
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6450698/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I'm getting NotSerializableException exception though I've implemented 'Serializable'

You haven't.

> java.io.NotSerializableException: chatservernazmus.User
>   public class userInfo implements Serializable{
>   public class User{

The `User` class must be serializable as well.

Comment: I've modified "public class User implements Serializable{"
Still I'm getting the err. Strange !!

Comment: If it's exactly the same error naming the same class, you haven't deployed it, or you haven't recreated the tream you're trying to read. If it names a new class, make that class serializable, and so on recursively until closure.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy ! I've recreated the .ser file and the code works.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to know for sure, but the cause of this is almost always that your class has a field that is not serializable (or that contains an object that contains a field, ...). Everything in an object, including everything that the object references and everything that those objects reference, must be serializable to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to the JVM for tracking the exact cause for `NotSerializableException`.

Eg: Add `SET CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` in the startup.bat